# How can I account for expressions when building control-flow graphs?

Tags: control-flow, static-analysis

How do statically typed programming languages build CFGs for programs containing expression-level control flow (e.g. ternary expressions, match expressions) which require transformation or extra information (i.e. type information, etc.)?

Here’s a concrete example:

```
let foo = "bar"
let k = match foo {
    "bar" -> 1,
    _ -> 0,
 }
print(foo, k)
```

My assumption is that the CFG for the whole program is first built and then patched afterwards when enough information becomes available for these kinds of expressions. I am just not sure how correct this is or how well it works in practice for efficiency reasons.

Comment: Welcome to the site! This is a good question, but can you be a bit clearer about how your concrete example shows extra information (e.g. type information) being needed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The simple answer is that many don't. Production compiler typically lower the initial AST into a simpler subset of the language (often more than once).  In many cases, typechecking and linting and other analysis steps that might require constructing a CFG happen *after* one or more of these lowering phases. A consequence of lowering is that expression-level control flow blocks (and other syntactic sugar) are removed.

For example, your code sample might be rewritten as such:

```
let foo = “bar”
let k; // k is declared, but not assigned yet
match foo {
    “bar” -> k = 1,
    _ -> k = 0,
}
print(foo, k)
```

From there, it should be more obvious as to how a CFG would be constructed.

The Rust compiler has a good, fairly straightforward overview of this process. You can start reading about it [here](https://rustc-dev-guide.rust-lang.org/overview.html) if you wish. Check out the sections on lowering, and try exploring some of the source code (it is very well documented).